# Chrome Printing Bug - Possible Workarounds?

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=658606

So there is an open issue with Chrome when printing where random characters will be left off.  Our office uses a lot of web printing in our applications, so this has began to hit us pretty hard.

Is there a way of getting around this issue?  From what I've heard from older Chrome printing bugs, sometimes web fonts can be the source of the issue, but our styles have the font set as follows, so I do not believe we're using web fonts here.

```
font-family "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
```

Any other ideas as far as a workaround for this printing issue?

Comment: I also tried setting the text to this, but it didn't seem to change anything.  `font-family Times, Georgia, serif;`